# grid using datatable jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I am creating a grid using data table plugin.

What i am not able to do is when there is a negative value in the array from where the data table is accessing the data then that value should appear in red color. Only the color of that value should be red not the whole cell. Can someone tell me how to do it

the fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aryan7987/77c9G/2/)

like in this example, the negative value is simply shown. i wan that the negative value should be indicated in a red color. only the value should be viewed in red color not the whole cell

the code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({"sPaginationType": "full_numbers"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the feature only on the version column ? Don't know if I really get what you want but here the code that enter code heres hould suit you :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('td:nth-child(4)').toArray().forEach( function (el) {
    $el = $(el);
    if ($el.html().length > 1 && $el.html()[0] === "-") {
      $el.css('color', 'red');
    }
  });
  $('#example').dataTable({"sPaginationType": "full_numbers"});
});​
```